# Adding all exception breakpoint for simulator but not for iPad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, breakpoints

I am trying to run my project on iPad and simulator at the same time. Now i want to add all exception breakpoint for simulator but i am afraid this will be applied to iPad as well. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to run my project on iPad and simulator at the same time.

Is it really possible? (debug it) As far as I know you cannot run and debug both on the device and simulator.
Choose one ;)

Comment: I can run project on both but not sure about debugging and indirectly thats the question. I need to do this because it crashes during a sync process and i want to avoid waiting 30 minutes for each sync and debug.

Comment: @akash Unless you are running more than 1 instance of xcode, you can only choose one device during a debug session, either your simulator or your device.  Regarding your wait of 30 minutes, typically, to expedite such scenarios, a developer would either change the sync time or simulate it using various means.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. _to expedite such scenarios, **a developer would either change the sync time** or simulate it using various means._ How do I change sync time?